# Building a react app but getting an error message that I can't locate: Warning: Can't perform a React state update on an unmounted component

Tags: javascript, reactjs, google-chrome-devtools

Im getting the below error and struggling to find the source of the problem. Based on the error I see in the console, should I investigate the lines; Toolbar.js:15? is there console suggesting the error is there?

Also, what is the general origin of this type of issues?

[image]

Comment: How should anyone be able to help without any code here? Could you please provide something to work with?

Comment: My question is more about directing me to the issue, instead of troubleshooting the issue. I'm trying to interpret what the console is yielding. This is why I didn't add the code at this point.

Comment: I see, so according to the error you probably forgot to add a cleanup function in some effect

Comment: I'm agree with @davbuc, check the useEffect hook or create one

Answer (score 1):

Usually this happens when you try to update the state on a component that is no longer mounted, which is pretty common for asynchronous operations such as timers or requests.

What some like to do is to set a flag on the `componentDidMount()` method and unset that flag on the `componentWillUnmount()` method, a flag commonly named `this.mounted`. With this, you can verify the state of your component before you call the `setState()` and make sure it is only called when the component is still mounted.

Let me know if you have any questions.

Hope this was helpful.